# Images not displayed properly when using img-fluid class

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

When adding the bootstrap class "img-fluid" to my images they don't appear, when inspecting the element it sets the image at 0x0 pixels.

The html:

```
<div class="col">
    <div class="row no-gutters">
      <div class="col">
        <img src="assets/images/placeholder.png" class="img-fluid" 
        alt="placeholder">
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <img src="assets/images/placeholder.png" class="img-fluid" alt="placeholder">
      </div>
      <div class="w-100"></div>
      <div class="col">
        <img src="assets/images/placeholder.png" class="img-fluid" alt="placeholder">
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <img src="assets/images/placeholder.png" class="img-fluid" alt="placeholder">
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

The images are supposed to be the same size as the parent(div.col) and be responsive to the parent.

Comment: It's because `.col` has a `flex-basis: 0` - this basically equates to `width: 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an answer based on my comment.

Because you have a `.col` element as a child of a `flex` parent, the `flex-basis` is set to `0`. That basically equates to `width: 0`.

To get around that, set the `flex-basis` to `auto` on the `.col` that are children of the `.row` element.

```css
.row>.col {
  flex-basis: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="col">
  <div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class="col">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/100x100" class="img-fluid" alt="placeholder">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/100x100" class="img-fluid" alt="placeholder">
    </div>
    <div class="w-100"></div>
    <div class="col">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/100x100" class="img-fluid" alt="placeholder">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/100x100" class="img-fluid" alt="placeholder">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, giving the col a defined grid size also seems to have fixed the problem. Changed col to col-6 which fixed it.